# Is there some location where certain bash or python scripts could be run from any directory?

Tags: bash

I want to add multiple custom made scripts to a location, say check_proxy.sh to run in terminal from any directory by `bash check_proxy.sh`. Just like there is such a way to open a directory by `cd mydirectory` defined in `$CDPATH` from any location.

I don't want to edit each time .bashrc to include any functions like:

```
func()
{
     python -i ~/Scripts/check_proxy.py
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the location to the PATH enviroment variable.

eg

```
$ mkdir ~/tmp/Alocation
$ echo "echo I am here" > ~/tmp/Alocation/my_test_script.sh
$ PATH=$PATH:~/tmp/Alocation
$ bash my_test_script.sh
I am here
$ cd /
$ bash my_test_script.sh
I am here
$ cd /etc
$ bash my_test_script.sh
I am here
$
```

Comment: Also, OP, you can append your `.bashrc` with a line that adds the location to the `$PATH`, so every time you fire up your shell, your scripts will be ready to go.